# How to render a Awesomium webview on a Canvas (or any other UI)?

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium

How can I render a WebView to a WPFCanvas in Awesomium 1.7? (using C#)
In the previous version of Awesomium, I used to use a WebControl and add it as a child of a canvas. Now I want to use Isolated Sessions, which seems possible in v1.7, but I can't display it. Also, should I be using Webcontrol along with WebSessions and WebViews? I'm clueless as there are not many sample out there yet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to use WebControls with isolated sessions, either programmatically by setting the `WebControl.WebSession` property (it's read-write on WebControls), or by using a `WebSessionProvider` in XAML. Read more here: http://wiki.awesomium.net/general-use/using-web-sessions.html

Comment: WebControl.WebSession is read-only. If I use WebControl.NativeView = myWebView.ProcessHandle, my program crashes. How do I assign a webview to a webcontrol?

Comment: `WebControl.WebSession` is not read-only. The property becomes read-only only after the `WebControl` goes live. The wiki article suggested in my answer, has an example of how to assign a `WebSession` to the `WebControl` in XAML. You can do the same programmatically, as long as you do it before the `WebControl` goes live. For example, in the host's constructor, right after `InitializeComponent`.